# Output Impedance of Passive Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have a circuit with resistors, capacitors and inductances. I need to plot the output impedance of this circuit for different values of two components in this network. Do you know a program (either freeware or matlab) which I can use to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LTspice is a free circuit simulator with endless help available online to get you started.

Comment: The output impedance will be a single value before you change the value of those two components you are talk about. Consider something like Microsoft Excel or Libre Calc. I don't know any programs that will plot an "impedance sweep" for two components. Type in formulas for the output impedance, assign new values for the two components, and plot a graph. However, you might come up with a custom expression on LTSpice if  you divide the output voltage by the output current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the closed form equation for Z using the (complex) numbers for impedance of R, C and L in MATLAB. Plot the complex impedance in whatever form is appropriate (perhaps magnitude and phase).

Then check by "cheating" and using [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlfGqh9an3gIVSx6GCh0s4QqQEAAYASAAEgIt6PD_BwE).

Comment: Or, because this is the real world, plot it in LTspice first, and don't bother finding the closed form solution unless you really need to :)

Comment: @Selvek Depending on whether this is a school problem set or a real world problem. Yup.

Comment: Well, if it's a school problem, that falls in the camp of "really need to"!

Comment: I need this for my bachelor thesis

Comment: What do you mean with "cheating" with LT Spice? I know that I can get an expression for the impedance via calculations (e.g. with MATLAB).  Is it possible to view the frequency plot of the Impedance in MATLAB and LT Spice?

Comment: @satu Sure, use a test signal in LTspice. For example, https://i.imgur.com/uSafHfa.png You can see that for low frequencies the impedance is 10\$\Omega\$ resistive and at high frequencies it's capacitive. In between, a resonant peak.  With MATLAB you have equations which you can just plot.